# How to have a timeout when using DispatchGroup?

Tags: swift

We can use a DispatchGroup in swift to add many tasks to the group.  The group will wait until all the tasks are complete before proceeding to the next codes.

```swift
let dg = DispatchGroup()
dg.notify(queue: .global()) {
   // run code here on completion
}
```

Is there a way to add a timeout for this dispatchGroup in case the tasks are taking too long to complete?

**[Edit]**

I am aware that `DispatchGroup.wait(timeout:)` adds a timeout. But this makes it synchronously wait. Is there a way that it is asynchronous using the `notify` method, but still have a timeout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the `DispatchGroup` to have a timeout asynchronously try:

```
var dg: DispatchGroup? = DispatchGroup()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
    self.dg = nil // after time out group is removed asynchronously
}
dg?.notify(queue: .global()) {
    // run code here on completion
}
```

Comment: creative. thanks. I thought there would have been a timeOut parameter as in the synchronous version. Congratz on 10k

Comment: You're welcome. I used the `DispatchGroup.wait(timeout:)` too. But, my requirement also made me switch to this method. Happy coding :)

Comment: amazing use case!!!

Answer (score 2):

Just to add an alternative way; to easily reuse this in multiple parts of your code, you could provide a DispatchGroup extension like this:

```swift
extension DispatchGroup {
    func notify(queue: DispatchQueue, timeout: TimeInterval, execute work: @escaping () -> ()) {
        var selfDestructingCompletion: (() -> ())?
        selfDestructingCompletion = {
            selfDestructingCompletion = nil
            work()
        }
        self.notify(queue: queue) {
            selfDestructingCompletion?()
        }
        queue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeout) {
            selfDestructingCompletion?()
        }
    }
}
```

Which then you would just use like this:

```swift
// 1. something you need to have for the dispatch group anyway
let someSerialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "someQueue")
let group = DispatchGroup()
for someApi in apiList {
    group.enter()
    someApi.call() {
        group.leave()
    }
}

// 2. the new method, just with the timeout parameter
group.notify(queue: someSerialQueue, timeout: 5.0) {
    // Run the completion for completing the tasks or for timeout in one place
}
```

This has the added benefits of:

- having no thread issues as long as you pass a serial queue (not true for the accepted answer)
- calling the completion only in one place when it's used

Just be sure to prefix the name of the method to some specific namespace of yours if you plan to insert this in a public library, to avoid clashes with other similar implementations of this extension.